# Append New Value to Text

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Eclipse IDE, java and Selenium Webdriver.  Here is my scenario: Using an .xlsx file, I feed values to a web form.  My code works fine, but if I run the scenario a 2nd time, my test fails because the values in my .xlsx file are already in use.  I need a way to increment the value by 1 each time I run the test so that my application doesn't throw an error because those values are already in use.  I know that I could just edit the .xlsx each time, but I want to see if there is an easier way.

Here is my code:

```
Utility.ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(Utility.Constant.Path_TestData + Utility.Constant.File_SellerNetwork,"Sheet1");
String sStoreNum = Utility.ExcelUtils.getCellData(1, 1);
SellerNetworkSetupPage.txt_StoreNum(driver).sendKeys(sStoreNum);

String sCustNum = Utility.ExcelUtils.getCellData(1, 2);
SellerNetworkSetupPage.txt_NewCustNum(driver).sendKeys(sCustNum);

String sNetworkName = Utility.ExcelUtils.getCellData(1, 3);
SellerNetworkSetupPage.txt_NetworkName(driver).sendKeys(sNetworkName);

SellerNetworkSetupPage.btn_Add(driver).click();
```

After SellerNetworkSetupPage.btn_Add(driver).click(); is performed, the application creates an account using those values.  I want to be able to run this code multiple times, with different values for sStoreNum, sCustNum and sNetworkName each time.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append a UID to key string values:

Something like this:

```
.sendKeys(sCustNum + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

If the target value is numeric, use this:

```
.sendKeys(sStoreNum + UUID.getLeastSignificantBits());
```

So each test will have its own primary key values.

Comment: thank you.  This will work, but is there a way to shorten the number of characters that are generated?  The given code generates a string that is 36 characters long.  Can that be shortened in any way?

Comment: i figured it out - adding .subSequence(0, length); shortens the character length to something more manageable for me

Comment: Yes, you can use `substring`, but be careful, the shorter the string the more probabilities it has a repeated value